# Reflect default price and strikethrough in mini cart item price in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello this code creates two discount classes, and then with a filter on the cart page it shows the regular price and the discounted price, how can I do to have the same visual result also on the mini cart??

[this is what i am trying to achieve in the minicart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xba1D.jpg)

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'bbloomer_quantity_based_pricing', 9999 );

```
function bbloomer_quantity_based_pricing( $cart ) {
    
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
    
    // Define discount rules and thresholds
    $threshold1 = 2; // Change price if items > 100
    $discount1 = 0.05; // Reduce unit price by 5%
    $threshold2 = 3; // Change price if items > 1000
    $discount2 = 0.1; // Reduce unit price by 10%
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) 
    {
        if( has_term( array('cartucce-inkjet'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
            if ( $cart_item['quantity'] >= $threshold1 && $cart_item['quantity'] < $threshold2 ) 
            {
                $price = round( $cart_item['data']->get_price() * ( 1 - $discount1 ), 2 );          
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
            } 
            elseif ( $cart_item['quantity'] >= $threshold2 ) 
            {
                $price = round( $cart_item['data']->get_price() * ( 1 - $discount2 ), 2 );
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
            }    
        }
    }   
}

function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

        // Get the product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get reqular price
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        
        // New price
        $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

        // NOT empty and NOT equal
        if ( ! empty ( $regular_price ) && $regular_price != $new_price ) {
            // Output
            $price_html = '<del>' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . wc_price( $new_price ) . '</ins>';        
        }
    }
    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
```